# Как сделать чтобы обработчик кнопки возвращал значение

Tags: c#

```
private int name_categoryComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (name_categoryComboBox.SelectedValue !=null)
              {

                comboBox_magazin_tovar.Items.Clear();
                Sqlzapros zapros = new Sqlzapros();
                var dt = zapros.select("SELECT name_tovar FROM Table_tovar WHERE id_category=" + name_categoryComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString());


                 for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    comboBox_magazin_tovar.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString());
                }
                return 1;
            }
        return 0;   
        }
```

Надо чтобы метод что-нибудь возвращал

Comment: возвращал куда? Код, которым вызывается этот обработчик, не ждет никакого возвращаемого значения.

Comment: Не нужно. Просто задавайте значение какому-нибудь полю.

Comment: А зачем вам такие грабли? Хотите извне узнать какой то результат, так вынесите это значение наружу, сделайте к примеру `private int MyResult` и с ним работайте. Кнопка не должна нечего возвращать, она должна что то выполнять!

Comment: Мне протестить надо метод. А как его протестить если метод ничего не возвращает

Comment: Переместите код из обработчика в другой метод, возвращающий целое число, и тестируйте этот новый метод (и его же вызывайте в обработчике).

Comment: то есть скопировать каждый метод в отдельный метод возвращающий значение? А как вынести данные за предел класса формы например в тестовый класс?

Comment: @user293746 Да, только не скопировать, а перенести.

Comment: Сделайте логирование - читайте лог.